# агрегатный запрос ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Надо посчитать количество подкатегорий для каждой категории

Пример данных:

```
Код_категории Код_подкатегории
1             1
2             2
3             1
4             3
5             2
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
Код_категории Код_подкатегории
1             2
2             2
3             2
4             1
5             2
```

Мой пример кода:

```
select Код_категории as Категория,
       (
           select count(Код_подкатегории)
           from Категория_товара
           where Код_категории != Код_подкатегории
       ) as Количество_категорий
from Категория_товара;
```

Comment: Из примера не понятно откуда должен взяться описанный результат. У вас там сейчас по одной подкатегории на каждую категорию

Comment: *Ожидаемый вывод* А почему в ожидаемом выводе вообще нет колонки с наименованием, говорящем о количестве?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял,

```
select t.Код_категории, count(t1.Код_подкатегории) Код_подкатегории 
from Категория_товара t
left join Категория_товара t1 on t.Код_подкатегории = t1.Код_подкатегории
group by t.Код_категории
```